# Using Devexpress with SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, signalr

I will need chat in my project.As far as i know **Devexpress** and **SigralR** are components.I would like to learn that,

May i use **Devexpress** with **SigralR** at the same project in asp.net mvc ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve done a project (although not MVC) where we used both the DevExpress control libraries in combination with SignalR.
They don’t bite each other if that’s what you mean.

In my situation it worked quite well. 
Because of the client-side possibilities of the DevEx controls, I think that the controls are particularly well suited for a combination with any other JS library.